# Core + Angular After Production Build can not access asset folder file

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

After Production Build,
I can Access [www.xyz.com/Assets/img/sample.png](http://www.xyz.com/Assets/img/sample.png) file but I can not access [www.xyz.com/Assets/img/sample.xkt](http://www.xyz.com/Assets/img/sample.xkt) file.
it will redirect to [www.xyz.com/index](http://www.xyz.com/index) page.
only can access .png and .jpg files.
how to allow to access all file in the assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty well explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#non-standard-content-types

Only 'standard' content types will go through automatically, although you can configure the static file middleware to serve everything.

```cs
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        DefaultContentType = "image/png"
    });
```

Although i should first check if a simple mapping works:

```cs
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

// Choose the right header here:
provider.Mappings[".xkt"] = "application/x-msdownload";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ...
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Comment: i just change few thing check this.

            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings[".xkt"] = "application/x-msdownload";
            return new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Assets")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Assets"),
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            
        }